# unable to display input number after save

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, two-way-binding

So I have a input name age, and another input name ageDif, ageDif is readonly and is depend on age. After I save, i rebind the ageDif and age. As the example below, the input value 20 for age is showing after save, but there is no value showing int the ageDif input box after save. However, I console.log both value, and both of them have correct values, just only one is showing.

html file

```
<div>
  <label>Age</label>
  <input required name="age" id="age" (keypress)="justnumeric($event);" (change)="calculateAgeDif()" [(ngModel)]="age"/>
</div>
  <label>Age Difference</label>
  <input name="age difference"  [(ngModel)]="ageDif"/>
</div>
</div>
  <label>Save</label>
  <input type ="button" (click)="saveAge()"/>
</div>
```

ts. file

```
justnumeric(event): boolean {    
      let pattern = /^([0-9])$/;
      let result = pattern.test(event.key);
      return result;
  }

  calculateAgeDif(){
    this.ageDif = 50- this.age;
  }

  saveAge(){
  this.saveAgeService.save(this.ageDif, this.age).pipe(first()).subscribe(res => {
    this.ageDif = res.ageDif;
    this.age = res.ageDif;
    console.log(this.ageDif);   //30 
    console.log(this.age);     //20 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

If it doesn't work for you, then you can implement `ChangeDetection`. So that you are forcing to detect changes after your API consumption.

**Correction:**
You are assigning `ageDif` in `age` variable.

**Suggestion:**
If you want the second `input` to be generated, then add `disabled` to the `input`.

I've added the solution at [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjqh9z?file=src/app/app.component.ts).